# Исправление синтаксической ошибки

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

«Предложения о туристическом бренде принимались Ростуризмом в ходе открытого конкурса: на него поступило более 10 тысяч **предложения**». Объясните ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...более десяти тысяч предложен**ий*** — после слова *тысяч* должно следовать слово, стоящее в родительном падеже.